# Using async with mongoose controllers/models

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, asynchronous

I can put every model within the callback of model but that kind of messy and hard to read. I found a npm called async but I have no idea how to use it.

```
User.find({
     "email":req.body.user_email
    }),
    function(err,response){
        if(!err){
            res.json(response);
        }
    })

AnotherModel.find(),
    function(err,response){
        if(!err){
            res.json(response);
        }
    })
```

I've read the doc but I don't understand it.

```
async.parallel([
    function(callback){ ... },
    function(callback){ ... }
], function(err, results) {
    // optional callback
};
```

What i want is in the end I just have to do ONE res.json after I merge data from multiple models and send it to the front end.

Comment: Have you considered using Promises for this cause. You code will be much cleaner. Check bluebird for node js you can promisify your functions and use .settle or .props to achieve what you want.

Comment: @nmargaritis aysnc is also a npm module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it like this

```
async.parallel([
  function(callback) {
    User.find({
        "email": req.body.user_email
      }),
      function(err, response) {
        if (!err) {
          callback(null,response)
        }
      })
},
function(callback) {
  AnotherModel.find(),
    function(err, response) {
      if (!err) {
        callback(null,response)
    })

}],
function(err, results) {
  if(!err){
    res.json(results);
  // You will get array of results in your results agrs
  }
};
```